# Why does Fix-It-All sometimes dry yellow?

Tags: patch

I've used the Fix-It-All brand patching product.  Sometimes my patches dry paper white, sometimes they end up yellow. Why might this be?

Comment: so you know where you patched?

Comment: It depends on the surface on which it's placed, on the water mixed in (e.g. containing iron) and on the mixing container.